# Issue with Firebase Cloud function.. not able to read parameters

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am not uunderstanding why this is not working, as it is basic.

Here is my code:

```
// Init cloud functions
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
// Used to access entire JSON Nodes as Admin...
admin.initializeApp();


exports.verifyIAP = functions.database.ref('/Users/{userid}/IAP/{groupid}/{rdate}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    const groupId = context.params.groupid;
    console.log('GroupID: ', groupId);

    const receiptDate = context.params.rdate;
    console.log('receipt Date: ', receiptDate);

    const userId = context.params.userid;
    console.log('UserID: ', userId);

    const receipt = snapshot.val().ReceiptData;
    console.log('receipt Data: ', receipt);

});
```

When the function triggers, the log shows all the variables as undefined!?

What am I missing!?

Comment: Where do you write to trigger the Cloud Function? How do you run the CF? Emulator? Shell? Deployed?

Comment: @frank Deployed

Comment: @frank and to trigger it i add a new row to the /Users/{userid}/IAP/{groupid}/{rdate} firebase realtime db node

Comment: I think you meant to tag @RenaudTarnec there, who commented. I merely added a tag to your question to ensure the code gets syntax highlighted.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec please see my comments above, tagged the wrong person, saw franks pic and thought it was him ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your function is working fine. I just tested it and the problem can be pointed on how you insert the data. For testing purposes, Here's a sample code I used to insert data and trigger the function:

```
// Import Admin SDK
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./*******.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://********.firebaseio.com/"  
});

var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("Users");
ref.set({
  "userId" : {
    "IAP" : {
      "groupId" : {
        "rdate" : {
          "ReceiptData" : "testVAl"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}).then(result => {
  console.log('done')
  process.exit(0)
});
```